# How to display the list response which inside the object - react js

Tags: reactjs

How to display the data in the below from the below json.

```
{
"a":
{
"b":[
  {"id":"ef718cce-1269-4fbd-827c-832f7824c025","name":"Veera6"},
  {"id":"0cda5ae9-e287-4666-804a-03f25e642d1f","name":"Veera9"},
  {"id":"31f8f042-dbc0-4dbf-ada8-b94c7e2d2a39","name":"Veera8"},
  {"id":"6292054c-8bfc-4d2d-b2f8-92e2bac5a578","name":"Veera7"},
  {"id":"c6756e5c-8fa5-40a9-ab92-5242bda97de3","name":"Veera10"}]
}
}
```

code snipped below.

```
render() {         

        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    {
                        this.headers.map(function(h) {
                            return (
                                <th key = {h.key}>{h.label}</th>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.tags.b.map(function(item, key) {       
                        return (
                                <tr key = {key}>
                                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )

    }
}
```

How to display the data in table. Here i need to get the array/list b. Tried different approaches to get the data from the object array but no luck.

Comment: What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what you were going to do in first < tr >.

Maybe this will point you to the right direction.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const headers = {
  a: {
    b: [
      { id: "ef718cce-1269-4fbd-827c-832f7824c025", name: "Veera6" },
      { id: "0cda5ae9-e287-4666-804a-03f25e642d1f", name: "Veera9" },
      { id: "31f8f042-dbc0-4dbf-ada8-b94c7e2d2a39", name: "Veera8" },
      { id: "6292054c-8bfc-4d2d-b2f8-92e2bac5a578", name: "Veera7" },
      { id: "c6756e5c-8fa5-40a9-ab92-5242bda97de3", name: "Veera10" }
    ]
  }
};

let keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(headers.a.b[0]);
let head = keys.map(propertyName => <th key={propertyName}>{propertyName}</th>);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>{head}</tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {headers.a.b.map(function(item, key) {
          return (
            <tr key={key}>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

So you should access **b** with **headers.a.b** and then *map()*.
Your **b** array is nested inside the headers **a** object, which is nested in **headers** object.

Result will be:

```
id                                      name
ef718cce-1269-4fbd-827c-832f7824c025    Veera6
0cda5ae9-e287-4666-804a-03f25e642d1f    Veera9
31f8f042-dbc0-4dbf-ada8-b94c7e2d2a39    Veera8
6292054c-8bfc-4d2d-b2f8-92e2bac5a578    Veera7
c6756e5c-8fa5-40a9-ab92-5242bda97de3    Veera10
```

Also be sure to check [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-shaw-qpy5t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) out.

Comment: tried this approach as well still getting error and it say "b" is Undefined.  TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined

Comment: @KakarlaVeeraShankaraRavindr check [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-shaw-qpy5t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) demo out

Comment: basically i am trying to consume the GraphQL API (Similar to RestAPI) which produces the response as given.

Comment: Please, check out the demo and let me know if this helped you.

Comment: still facing issues. placed code in the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-meitner-lp9hs

Comment: @KakarlaVeeraShankaraRavindr [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-sun-o0yjk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Please check.

Comment: super. this works fine. thank you for quick resolution

Comment: @KakarlaVeeraShankaraRavindr glad it helped. Do not forget to upvote the answer and mark it as 'accepted'. Wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.state.tags.a.b.map
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once :

```
{
                        this.state.tags.a.b.map(function(item, key) {       
                        return (
                                <tr key = {key}>
                                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GET_GRPHQL_API = gql`
{
  getTags
  {
    id
    tagName
    tagDesc
    tagVersion
    tagVersion
  }
  }
  `
function App() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_GRPHQL_API);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>


<table>
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data &&
          data.getTags &&
          data.getTags.map(function(item, key) {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.tagName}</td>
                  <td>{item.tagDesc}</td>
                  <td>{item.tagVersion}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```